# QlikSense version control with Git?

Tags: git, github, qliksense

I use Git to track my Qlikview dashboards using the method described in this link:
https://biexperience.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/using-git-with-qlikview-to-version-control-your-projects/

I am unable to find documentation to help me track QlikSense dashboards using Git. Any solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

These projects might help you out -- I haven't used them personally but have done some research in the past about how QlikSense might be integrated with source control: these tools appear to let you export a QlikSense App to JSON and also restore from such. That JSON can be stored in source control.

https://github.com/mindspank/serializeapp

https://github.com/countnazgul/QS-backup-and-restore-app

Answer (score 1):

You could try - https://gitoqlik.com

This project is a Chrome extension that adds version control in the built-in editor of Qlik Sense.

It integrates your app with repositories in Gitlab, Github, BitBucket